# pyspark cannot parse timestamp in json

Tags: python, json, timestamp, pyspark

for example, given the following json (named 'json':

```
{"myTime": "2016-10-26 18:19:15"}
```

and the following python script:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext  
from pyspark import SparkConf     
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('simpleTest')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
print sc.version
json_file = 'json'
df = sqlContext.read.json(json_file,timestampFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
df.printSchema()
```

The output is:

```
2.0.2
root
 |-- myTime: string (nullable = true)
```

I expected the schema to be defined as timestamp.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a schema explictly:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, TimestampType

schema = StructType([StructField("myTime", TimestampType(), True)])

df = spark.read.json(json_file, schema=schema, timestampFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

This will output:

```
>>> df.collect()
[Row(myTime=datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 26, 18, 19, 15))]
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- myTime: timestamp (nullable = true)

>>>
```

Comment: so the point in defining "timestampFormat" is how timestamp strings will be interpreted when tried to fit into a column of "TimestampType()" 
in a schema ?

Answer (score 0):

Additional to Dat Tran solution, you can also directly apply `cast` to dataframe column after reading the file.

```
# example
from pyspark.sql import Row
json = [Row(**{"myTime": "2016-10-26 18:19:15"})]
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(json).toDF()

# using cast to 'timestamp' format
df_time = df.select(df['myTime'].cast('timestamp'))
df_time.printSchema()

root
 |-- myTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Comment: would it be an impact on performance to do it this way on large datasets, since we preform 2 data-frame operations?

Comment: It will take a little more time but not too much IMO since this is just applying `cast` function to the column.

Comment: You can also replace out cast column back to original dataframe.